# Unable to fetch records using axios in Laravel 5.5

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, axios, vue-resource

I'm trying to fetch records using axios. 
But problem is that I'm getting the error in the console which is written below:
GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/getData 500 (Internal Server Error)

Here is my component in which I'm trying to get the data

```
<template lang="html">
  <div class="getData">
    <h1 class="text-center text-muted">Recently Added Chemicals</h1>
    <div class="table-responsive">
      <table class="table table-striped">
        <tr>
          <th>Chemical Name</th>
          <th>Status</th>
          <th>Stock</th>
        </tr>
        <tr v-for="list in lists">
          <td>{{list.chem_name}}</td>
          <td>
            <p v-if="lists.is_active = 1" style="color: green;">Active</p>
            <p v-else style="color: red;">Not Active</p>
          </td>
          <td>
            <p v-if="lists.is_stocked = 1" style="color: green;">In Stock</p>
            <p v-else style="color: red;">Out Of Stock</p>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data () {
    return {
      lists: {},
      errors: {}
    }
  },
  mounted(){
    axios.get('getData').then((response) => this.lists = response.data).catch((error) => console.log(this.error));
  }
}
</script>
```

Then my getData function in resource controller

```
public function getData(){
      $id = Auth::user()->id;
      $data = chemType::where('user_id', $id)->orderBy('id', 'DESC')->get();
      return response()->json(200, $data);
    }
```

Please help!!!

Comment: Please look in your developer tools in the network tab and you should see the get request with the status 500 error next to it.  Click on it and then 'Response' to get at the full error message if possible.

Comment: The Response tab is saying 'Successfully Added'. I'm trying to add a text field and on the same component I'm also adding another child component to show the latest records without reloading page.

Comment: What happens if you simply `return $data` since Laravel will automatically return a json response any how.

Comment: This is happening if I simply `return $data` 
app.js:50923 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of undefined
    at app.js:50923
    at <anonymous>

Comment: Ok so no 500 error?  Else if there was an error it would caught.  Are you certain that your query is actually returning something?

Comment: yes , it is returning the objects. But not the new one's that I add.
To see the new one , I have to reload the page , then it shows up. And so on.!!!

Comment: Oh well yes you are going to have to refresh the page because you are only making the axios call on the mounted() lifecycle hook.

Comment: I can try to help you further in the stackoverflow chat since it prompting us to do so.

Comment: But , I do not want this, what should I change to get it work like I want?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164787/discussion-between-skribe-and-danish-tahir).

Comment: Please Check that Auth Model is included or not in the controller.

Answer (score 1):

500 error means error on backend, look at chrome dev tools network to look at the exception thrown.

I think the error is in *response()->json()*. The first parameter should be $data

Comment: yes, I did that as well. I added the $data parameter at first but when I add a new record , it is not adding the newely created row automatically. For that I still need to refresh the page. 
What to do now?

Comment: I did console.log(response.data) and it works fine. It gave the records , but when I tried to add a new record , it invoked the error again and did not added the newly created row in console.log(response.data).
But when , I'll refresh the page , it will be added , And I don't want that!
I want to automatically add the data to the table when I press create without reloading the page.

Comment: this time the error is this.

app.js:50923 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of undefined
    at app.js:50923
    at <anonymous>

Comment: Add a new record?

Well you need another Vue method for that. You are just fetching your db records in mounted() not adding as I can see.

Comment: So , what to do now ? I'm using save method in a addNewChemicalName.vue and then using another component getChemicalData.vue in which I'm using mounted method to fetch records. 
And in the first component , I'm importing the second component , where I'm trying to display the data without refreshing. But still stuck there

Comment: I recommend to take a look at this for handling parent-children events

https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Using-v-on-with-Custom-Events

Can´t help you without further code.

Answer (score 0):

Confirm you have the following line in your bootstrap.js file

```
window.axios.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'] = 'XMLHttpRequest';
```

And also check that you have the following in the header of your html page.

```
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

Answer (score 0):

I did it by doing changes in my resource controller. What was wrong in the controller is that , I was not sending the json response after creating the new record. So one thing I did sent the json response. 
On vue part , I used $emit function from my parent component to child and in child I refreshed the record using that $emit function and yes, I am now getting newly created records without any page reloading.

Answer (score 0):

Please Check that Your URL is Working or Not. Means it is fetching data in Controller or Not. It is giving some response or Not. I have faced the same problem but My URL was not fetching any data because My Model was not included. SO after including the model, my problem was solved.